# Hypothetical Computer Marc-32

Tags: numerical-methods, number-systems, floating-point

I'm studying numerical analysis and i am stuck with one of my exercises. In the book "Numerical Analysis: Mathematics of scientific Computing" they introduce a hypothetical computer called MARC-32. In the book the computer is a 32-bits computer representing a nonzero real number with the form: x = ±q * 2^m

with the allocation:

- sign of the real number x: 1 bit
- biased exponent (integer e): 8 bits
- mantissa part (real number f): 23 bits

[marc-32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxueF.png)

My problem is that i really do not understand the computer and hence can not solve the following problems:

Determine whether the following numbers are machine numbers in the Marc-32:

- 10^40
- 2^-1+2^-29
- 1/3
- 1/5

I have read the chapter a couple of times and still i don't get it. I really want to know what they mean by the hypothetical computer and how to solve it.

Comment: What about the description of the representation is it you don't understand?

Comment: It is relevant to add how the true exponent is computed from the biased exponent, i.e., what is the shift used by the Marc-32. The answers depend on  the exact shift. Moreover, can you determine the exact binary representation of the four numbers?

Comment: @CarlChristian - while technically you are correct, I have a hard time believing it would be anything other than e = m + 128, thereby allowing exponents of 2 from -128 to +127.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: The shift used in IEEE single precision is 127 and not 128. Assuming OP is referring to a book by Kincaid and Cheney, the Marc-32 has a permissible range of exponents from -126 to 127. This is consistent with IEEE SP where the smallest exponent, i.e. -127 is used for zero or subnormal numbers, while the largest exponent 128 is used for infinities or NaN.

Comment: @CarlChristian - all of which has no impact on the answers to the questions asked, because none of the questions involve exponents in that range.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Surely our objective should be to eliminate the OP's explicitly stated problem, i.e., insufficent understanding of the Marc-32. Identifying the correct shift is a necessary step towards that goal.

Comment: @CarlChristian - I would say the the explicitly stated problem is understanding the Marc-32 *sufficiently to answer the questions*. A complete specification of every detail of the Marc-32's operation is not necessary for that task. If there are other questions or tasks that delve into the precise handling of high exponent magnitude numbers, then those details would become important. But for the issues presented in this question, they are completely irrelevant.

Comment: @PaulSinclair No. The easiest path to showing that $10^40$ is not a machine number depends on knowing if it lies in the representational range or not. If it lies in the representational range, then we must recognize that storing the exact mantissa requires more than the 23 bits which are available. This is not hard, but why add unnecessary branches to an answer when a simple edit from the OP would clarify the issue?

Comment: @CarlChristian - The easiest path to handling $10^{40}$ is to multiply $40 \times \log_2 10 > 132$. Problem solved.

Comment: @PaulSinclair. Your analysis is *only* valid if the Marc-32 mirrors IEEE single precision and caps the exponent below $132$. We *still* do not have the necessary confirmation from the OP.

Comment: To clarify your questions I have these text excerpts:



"The floating-point representation for a single-precision real number in the hypothetical 32-bit computer Marc - 3 2 is divided into three fields as shown in figure 2.1" - the figure I attached.



"and the values e = 0 and e = 255 are reserved for special cases such as ±0, ±infinity, and NaN (Not a Number). Since m = e - 127 , we take -126 < m < 127 and the Marc-32 can handle numbers as small as 2^(-126) =1.2 x 10 ^(-38) and as large as (2 - 2^(-23))*2^(127) = 3.4 * 10^(38)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write $x$ in binary, it would looks something like this (as an example):
$$x=1010011.011010010001_b$$
Then you convert it to the binary version of scientific notation:
$$x = 1.010011011010010001_b \times 2^{110_b}$$

For this example,

- The number is positive, so the sign bit would be $1$ (or possibly $0$, depending on the system architecture - for these problems, it doesn't matter which is used.)
- The exponent $m = 6 = 110_b$. But we want to store positive and negative exponents in the eight bits, and there is no sign bit. So we bias the result by adding a value. 8 bits can store 256 different values, so if we alot half of them for negative exponents, that is 128. This means the range of allowable exponents is from $-128$ to $+127$. When the exponent is stored, we add $128$ so the value we store is from $0$ to $255$. For the example, the exponent stored is $110_b + 10000000_b = 10000110_b$.
- The bit in front of the point is always $1$. This is what defines the exponent value. It is the exponent that brings the leading $1$ to be right in front of the "decimal" point. Since this bit is *always* $1$, there is no need to store it. The "mantissa" is the part of the number to the right of the point. In the example, the mantissa is $010011011010010001_b$. Since we have 23 bits, it is actually stored as:
  $$01001101101001000100000$$

Comment: I should note about the final bullet, that when $x = 0$, the bit in front of the decimal point cannot be $1$, even though it is for every other number. It is usual to assign a particular value as representing $0$ (for example, all 32 bits being 0), instead of interpreting per the scheme described above.

Comment: Thank you Paul for the answer, it was really understandable with that step by step guide. So let me try to tell you what I understood. 

1) First I convert my decimal number (which I want to determine is a marc 32 number) to binary
2) Then I convert my exponent to binary
3) Now I can write the number as the binary version of scientific notation
4) I want to store the exponent as a 8 bit so I add the binary number 10000000
5) Now I look at the mentissa and add/discard to 23 bits
6) and finally I have the number x = 1.(23 bits mantissa)^(8 bits exponent). Did I understand it correctlly?

Comment: and i have just tried to convert 10^40 to binary, it is impossible!?

Comment: It is not impossible, but the result will be roughly 132 bits, of which about 92 will be significant (i.e., either $1$ or followed by a $1$ somewhere in lower orders). And that is all you need to know. As Carl Christian points out, you need to double-check that the Marc 32 doesn't do something weird to allow exponents greater than 128 (even though it would be rather pointless to do so). But unless it does, the fact that $10^{40}$ has an base-2 exponent of 132 rules out this as being a machine number, so there is no reason to check it any farther.

Comment: As for your steps, I was just trying to clarify the basic storage scheme to improve your understanding, not give step-by-step instructions on solving the problem. As you've noticed, following those steps in that order can be daunting. But you don't have to actually do it - you just have to figure out if it will be possible. That is usually easier. $10^{40}$ fails because it is relatively easy to find the base 2 exponent. It is the only one that actually takes a calculator or paper to figure out. The second is matter of counting, and the other two a matter of divisibility.

Comment: I dont think I understand it yet. So how do I determine if 10^40 is a machine number? I just check if it is easy to find the base 2 exponent or not?

Comment: I am little bit puzzled right now

Comment: No. You find the base 2 exponent is 132 ($\lfloor \log_2(10^{40})\rfloor$). You note "the highest exponent that can be stored is 127 (or 126, or whatever you determine from the exact specification)", then you say "Well, obviously since the exponent of $10^{40}$ is too high to be stored, it is not a machine number". That works for the first number. The other three do not have exponent problems - the reasons they cannot be stored are different. If you don't see why, then I do recommend trying to convert them to binary.

Comment: So I tried to convert 2^-1+2^-29 to binary number and it gives me 0.1 which is equal to if i just converted 0.5 to binary

Comment: I also tried to convert 1/3 and 1/5 and the binary number is infinite. the binary number of 1/3 has a loop of 1010... and the binary number of 1/5 has a loop of 0011... So i think in the problem here is that the mantissa can only store 23 bits and these numbers are infinite, thus they are no marc 32 machine numbers. Am i right here? And I do not now how to argument for 2^-1+2^-29

Comment: $2^{-1} = 0.1_b$. But you were supposed to convert $2^{-1}+2^{-29}$. How did you lose the contribution from $2^{-29}$?. As for 1/3 and 1/5 you are exactly right. It would take infinite bits to represent either one, and you only have 23, so they are not machine numbers. That is the divisibility issue: Because the denominators are not powers of 2, the binary expansion is infinite.

Comment: So I tried again to convert 2^-1+2^-29 and this time I got 0.1(28 zeros)1... so again it would take infinite bits to store this

Comment: 29 is a far cry short of "infinite". The binary expansion terminates after the 29th bit. There are no further 1s. And the representation would require only 28 bits (exponent = -1, mantissa = (27 zeros)1). However, since you only have 23 bits available, this number is still not representable.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Why is the exponent -1 when converting  2^-1+2^-29 to base 2 binary? isnt the exponent supposed to be 8 bits

Comment: @MarcusF - I was not trying to describe how the exponent was stored, only pointing that because the binary-scientific-notation exponent of the actual number was $-1$, the mantissa would be (if storable) 27 zeros followed by a one. The point is, since that mantissa will not fit in the available space, the number cannot be stored, regardless of how the exponent is handled.